# How to get the lastpage of each section, so that I could put it on the headline

Tags: beamer

How to get the lastpage of each section, so that I could put it on the headline.

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\usepackage{lastpage}

\begin{document}
\section{1}
\begin{frame}
123 Total \pageref{LastPage} pages

How to get the pages of section 1?
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
1234
\end{frame}
\section{1}
\begin{frame}
1235
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can highlight code in your post using back-ticks. To highlight code-blocks, either indent them by four spaces or use the `{}` on the gui.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In order to access the first and last page of the current `part`, `section` or `subsection` the `beamer`offers the commands `\insertZstartpage` and `\insertZendpage` with `Z`= `part`, `section` or `subsection`. 
A short description of these commands can be found on page 66 of the beamer userguide.

MWE with a very simple headline:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeamertemplate{headline}{%
  \parbox{\linewidth}{\vspace{10pt} \hspace{10pt} \insertsectionstartpage / \insertsectionendpage}}


\begin{document}
\section{1}
\begin{frame}
Section 1 starts at: \insertsectionstartpage

Section 1 ends at: \insertsectionendpage
\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
1234
\end{frame}

\section{2}
\begin{frame}
First frame of section 2

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```